# OnGesturePerformedListener Error - Android

Tags: java, android, gesture

I am trying to implement a GestureOverlay and Listener in my application so it can perform actions based on input gestures.  I have tried many different things but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

From onCreate method:

```
GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gesturesoverlay);
gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

From main.xml if it is of any help:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
  android:id="@+id/gesturesoverlay"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1.0" 
  android:gestureColor="#FF33B5E5"
  android:uncertainGestureColor="#FF33B5E5" />
```

The error I get is from the gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this); line.  The error is

> The method addOnGesturePerformedListener(GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener) in the type GestureOverlayView is not applicable for the arguments (GestureLauncher).

Thanks again.

Comment: Is your class implementing GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the argument to `addOnGesturePerformedListener()` needs to be an object that implements `OnGesturePerformedListener`. You are passing `this` which is evidently a `GestureLauncher` but does not implement `OnGesturePerformedListener`.

Comment: I tried implementing OnGesturePerformedListener to the my main activity.  The error is fixed but it seems like the listener isn't working, I should get a toast message regardless of the accuracy of my gesture but I get nothing.  Any way to check to see if the listener is working for sure?

Comment: @user1155694 I'm not sure. You can try logging the calls to `onGesturePerformed`. You can also implement `OnGestureListener` and log everything that goes through there. Can you post your entire `onCreate` method?